# Press button on website from form

Tags: c#, getelementbyid

Can someone help me out here?
**I am using C# 2010 Windows Form Application**
How can i press a button in web from form (WebBrowser Control)?
I know about the: `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByID("ID HERE"),` but i doesn't understand this..

Here is the code for the button: http://pastebin.com/34tmweLd

This code is the the "Poke back" button on facebook, can anyone help me out please?

I have tried like:

```
web.Document.GetElementById("u_jsonp_6_0").InvokeMember("click");
```

But it doesn't work, and how will it be if i wan't to poke all the people that have poked me? If there is more than one person?

EDIT:  I tried this: (but didn't work)

```
HtmlElement element = web.Document.GetElementById("u_jsonp_6_0");
        if (element == null)
        {
            statusLabel.Text = "ID NOT FOUND";
        }
        else
        {
            statusLabel.Text = "ID FOUND";
            HtmlDocument document = web.Document;
            document.GetElementById("u_jsonp_6_0").InvokeMember("Click");
        }
```

Comment: By using WebBrowser Control you can manipulate html elements loaded into the browser control,you can click buttons and make interactions with the page as a user is supposed to do through programming.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/34tmweLd link is not working !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HtmlDocument document = webBrowser.Document;
document.GetElementById("u_jsonp_6_0").InvokeMember("Click");
```

The code above performs the click in the WebBrowser Control for you. If you want to assign an event handler, do this:

```
document.GetElementById("u_jsonp_6_0").Click 
                             += new HtmlElementEventHandler(el_Click);
```

with:

```
void el_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
     // Do something
}
```

Comment: How about when i have 2 pokes? Then the ID might change?

Comment: Sorry! I don't understand. What do you mean? The ID must be unique. What's change?

Comment: make sure you putted your code in DocumentCompleted event handle

Comment: I putted it in a button1_click event, so it should work if i'm on the poke page: http://www.facebook.com/pokes?notif_t=poke

Comment: If you work with facebook.com, you should use facebook API or it's SDK. Because all of elements in facebook document will be changed their id or class every time.

Comment: Uhm, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Could help you to underestand getElementById: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById